# Find multiple based on a single criterium (arrayfun)

Tags: windows, matlab

I am trying to recieve all values from a variable (b) when using a criterium based on another variable (a) (it's like the =IF function in excel). like this:

Example:

(a): 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

(b): 3 6 3 5 6 4 5 4

my criteria is

```
(a) = 2
```

my reply has to be:

```
(b) = 6 3 5
```

I tried to find a solution using arrayfun, like this:

```
arrayfun(@(x) b(find(a == x, 1, 'first')), 2)
```

obviously, it only answers the 6, the first number that matches the criterium. Can I somehow formulate arrayfun correctly? Or do I need a whole other function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just want:

```
a = [ 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
b = [3 6 3 5 6 4 5 4]
b(a == 2)


ans =

 6     3     5
```

If a was a matrix then:

```
a = [ 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3; ...
      1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4; ]
b = [3 6 3 5 6 4 5 4]

b(a(1,:)==2)

ans =

   6     3     5
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I want! Thanks for the answer.
But now I face another problem. The (a) is a matrix and (b) only consists of a single vector. When I command the program to search in a specific row, it does not comply. 
Example: 
a(1,:,1)(b((1,:) == 2)
results in: 
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
Would you know an answer to this?